# select random cell by index only in upper or lower triangle

Tags: r, matrix

Given a random square matrix, we can pick a random cell doing:

```
set.seed(22)
d <- matrix(sample(100:199, 100), nrow = 10)
index <- sample(1:100, 1)
d[index]
```

**1)** How can we do the same thing but only select from either the upper or lower triangle

**2)** How could this be extended to only pick a cell in the `upper.tri` that has a particular condition i.e. `>103`

I so far have this

```
 sample( which(d[upper.tri(d, diag = TRUE)] > 103 ), 1 )
```

but it returns the index in the context of the length of `upper.tri` not the whole matrix...

Answer (score 0):

```
which(d > 127 & upper.tri(d, diag = TRUE) == TRUE )
```

gets all the indexes of d that meet the conditions

`sample` can then be use to randomly select one or more of these

Comment: i believe this is an answert to the question i posted

Answer (score 0):

Nested conditions could be used,

`d[upper.tri(d,diag=TRUE)]` will subset all the upper triangle observations including the diagonal

Among these if we wish to test a condition say `x > 127`, these two could be combined into a single condition:

`d[upper.tri(d,diag=TRUE)] > 127`

and to get observations which obey both conditions we pass the combined condition to `d[ ]`

`d[ d[upper.tri(d,diag=TRUE)] > 127 ]`

To get a random sample from the above `sample(z,1)` is used where `z = d[ d[upper.tri(d,diag=TRUE)] > 127 ]`

all-in-one

`sample(d[ d[upper.tri(d,diag=TRUE)] > 127 ],1)`

Comment: It would be great if you add an explanation to your code that you have suggested.

Comment: I wanted the index not the value, sorry but this doesnt answer the question